# Add link for downloadable products in Expresso Store's emails?

Tags: expresso-store, html-email, product

Exp:resso Store 2.3.1 and EE 2.8.1.

How can I include a download link right in the Order Confirmation email that Store sends out for any downloadable products in that order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including download links is perfectly possible.

First, set the Email Formatting to "HTML", since Store's [Download Tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/download_tag.html) outputs HTML.

Second, use the same code in the email template that you would use in a regular EE template to display download links. Here's an example:

```
<ul>
    {items}
    <li>
        {title}
        {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {exp:store:download url="{product_file}" order_id="{order_id}"}
                Download
            {/exp:store:download}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </li>
    {/items}
</ul>
```

If you have multiple product channels (eg. "Books", "Music", etc) instead of a single "Products" channel, you need to add in some conditionals to only show download links for products in channels that have them. In the following example, only the "Music" channel has a downloadable product field:

```
<ul>
    {items}
    <li>
        Title: {title}
        {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {if channel_short_name == 'music'}
                {exp:store:download url="{music__file}" order_id="{order_id}"}
                    Download
                {/exp:store:download}
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </li>
    {/items}
</ul>
```